# Convert complex string to date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which pulls data from RSS Feeds and saves. The RSS feed format of representing publication date and time seems difficult to be converted into a MYSQL DATE(TIME) format. It comes as *Thu, 14 Jan 2021 17:11:05 +0000* for example. So when I use `STR_TO_DATE` to try converting it, it returns null since `STR_TO_DATE` doesn't go with such formats. Also, I can't even trim parts of the string and make it work with `STR_TO_DATE`. Of course, other functions like `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` won't work with that kind of string. How can I convert such a complex string to a MYSQL date format? I'm trying to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE 1 ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE('Thu, 14 Jan 2021 17:11:05 +0000', '%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to complete your date format.
You can truncate the parts you don't want afterwards.
As an alternative you could use `substring` before convertion.

> ```
> select str_to_date(
> 'Thu, 14 Jan 2022 17:11:05 +0000',
> '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%i:%s +%f') formatted_date
> ```
>
> ```
> | formatted_date             |
> | :------------------------- |
> | 2022-01-14 17:11:05.000000 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2a746a999dfb2492cc1fa9afba51f911)*